# How to set the order of the tests in QUnit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, qunit

I write the test set for my constructor. This constructor creates and initializes some properties. My tests test each that property. Also I have some array which contains the names of tested properties. My tests add into that array the names of properties which they tested.

After that test set will be done must be launched my special test: it compares the set of properties which was defined by my constructor with the contents of the array which contains the set of tested properties. If all properties was tested then the test passes, otherwise it fails.

Last test allows to me to be sure that I tested all properties. Later if I add new property then this test immediately let me know that I am to add the new test or the set of tests.

```
(function(){
    let instanceCheckedProps = [];

    QUnit.test("Node() ctor: check the instance's id property.", 
    function (assert) {

        let prop = 'id';

        // here is my test code...

        instanceCheckedProps.push(prop);
    });

    // Here is my other tests...

    QUnit.test('Node() ctor : check if all properties have been tested',
        function (assert) {

        let node = new Tree.Node();

        let allPropsChecked = true;
        let instanceAllProps = Object.keys(node);

        for (let i = 0; i < instanceAllProps.length; i++) {

            if (!instanceCheckedProps.includes(instanceAllProps[i])) {

                allPropsChecked = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        assert.ok(allPropsChecked);
    });
})();
```

But I see that QUnit launches my tests not in the same sequence that they were written: my special test is launched first.

How can I solve it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting QUnit to run tests in order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884337/getting-qunit-to-run-tests-in-order)

Answer (score 1):

This is expected, and correct, behavior. In ANY testing scenario, the [tests should be atomic](http://defragdev.com/blog/?p=714). In other words, you **should not** make one test depend on others. Your last test is NOT a test at all, and should not be included. Instead, you should adopt a development strategy where you write the test BEFORE you write the code to ensure that there is always a test for each property.

What you have above is an [anti-pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/antipatterns/software-development-antipatterns) and will lead to more problems!! I **highly encourage you to not do this.**

That all said, if you are unwilling to change your practices and feel that you just want to implement the workaround and not do things correctly, then you can explore the `reorder` [configuration option](https://api.qunitjs.com/config/QUnit.config) in QUnit.